# MySQL sólo devuelve texto no interpreta html

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, datatables

estoy usando el **Live Add Edit Delete Datatables Records using PHP Ajax**

Todo funciona perfecto con el texto es decir si añado algo de texto MySQL lo guarda y devuelve perfecto.

Pero al colocarle por ejemplo código en html no lo interpreta como tal y lo devuelve como texto es decir:

```
<img src="https://imagen.jpg">
```

Lo devuelve tal cual y no devuelve la imagen.

lo mismo sucede con

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Ir</a>
```

Lo devuelve tal cual y no devuelve el enlace.

No se como puedo hacer que devuelva el código html interpretado como tal...  O sea, que al escribir el código html de una imagen o enlace, devuelva la imagen no el texto.

## *Aquí esta el código que uso:*

```
index.php
-
        <html>
     <head>
      <title>Live Add Edit Delete Datatables Records using PHP Ajax</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
      <style>
      body
      {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       background-color:#f1f1f1;
      }
      .box
      {
       width:1270px;
       padding:20px;
       background-color:#fff;
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       border-radius:5px;
       margin-top:25px;
       box-sizing:border-box;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="container box">
       <h1 align="center">Live Add Edit Delete Datatables Records using PHP Ajax</h1>
       <br />
       <div class="table-responsive">
       <br />
        <div align="right">
         <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="alert_message"></div>
        <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Frist Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <th></th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      fetch_data();
    
      function fetch_data()
      {
       var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "order" : [],
        "ajax" : {
         url:"fetch.php",
         type:"POST"
        }
       });
      }
      
      function update_data(id, column_name, value)
      {
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id, column_name:column_name, value:value},
        success:function(data)
        {
         $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
         $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
         fetch_data();
        }
       });
       setInterval(function(){
        $('#alert_message').html('');
       }, 5000);
      }
    
      $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
       var id = $(this).data("id");
       var column_name = $(this).data("column");
       var value = $(this).text();
       update_data(id, column_name, value);
      });
      
      $('#add').click(function(){
       var html = '<tr>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
       html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insert</button></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
       $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
      });
      
      $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
       var first_name = $('#data1').text();
       var last_name = $('#data2').text();
       if(first_name != '' && last_name != '')
       {
        $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name},
         success:function(data)
         {
          $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
          $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
          fetch_data();
         }
        });
        setInterval(function(){
         $('#alert_message').html('');
        }, 5000);
       }
       else
       {
        alert("Both Fields is required");
       }
      });
      
      $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
       {
        $.ajax({
         url:"delete.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{id:id},
         success:function(data){
          $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
          $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
          fetch_data();
         }
        });
        setInterval(function(){
         $('#alert_message').html('');
        }, 5000);
       }
      });
     });
    </script>
```

### insert.php

```
 <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
    if(isset($_POST["first_name"], $_POST["last_name"]))
    {
     $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["first_name"]);
     $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["last_name"]);
     $query = "INSERT INTO user(first_name, last_name) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name')";
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
     {
      echo 'Data Inserted';
     }
    }
    ?>
```

### update.php

```
 <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
    if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {
     $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["value"]);
     $query = "UPDATE user SET ".$_POST["column_name"]."='".$value."' WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
     {
      echo 'Data Updated';
     }
    }
    ?>
```

### delete.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
  echo 'Data Deleted';
 }
}
?>
```

### fetch.php

```
 <?php
    //fetch.php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
    $columns = array('first_name', 'last_name');
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user ";
    
    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
    {
     $query .= '
     WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
     OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
     ';
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
     ';
    }
    else
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
    }
    
    $query1 = '';
    
    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
     $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
    
    $number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));
    
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);
    
    $data = array();
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="first_name">' . $row["first_name"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="last_name">' . $row["last_name"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>';
     $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    
    function get_all_data($connect)
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
    
    $output = array(
     "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
     "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
     "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
     "data"    => $data
    );
    
    echo json_encode($output);
    
    ?>
```

### Base De Datos

```
    --
    -- Database: `testing`
    --
    
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    
    --
    -- Table structure for table `user`
    --
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    
    --
    -- Dumping data for table `user`
    --
    
    INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Smith'),
    (5, 'Peterson', 'Parker'),
    (7, 'Rock', 'Madison'),
    (8, 'Titan', 'Edge');
    
    --
    -- Indexes for dumped tables
    --
    
    --
    -- Indexes for table `user`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `user`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
    
    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
    --
    
    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `user`
      MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

Comment: ¿Dónde ocurre el problema exactamente, en qué parte de todo el código que has compartido?

Comment: mira aqui te dejo un ejemplo hechale un vistazo y veras el error

https://jflabur.000webhostapp.com/lista/

Comment: intento que muestre el enlace y la imagen